# How to add foreign key to MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, alter-table

I use `MySQL` with `InnoDB` engine. I double-checked type of columns. But always have:

`Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`

I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE `mail`.`boxes`  
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id 
    FOREIGN KEY (id) 
    REFERENCES `mail`.`users` (id)
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE `mail`.`boxes` 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
  REFERENCES `mail`.`users` (id)
```

Nothing works(((

Please, help, what I am doing wrong (except choosing MySQL :-) )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If table contains data then you are not able to add foreign key you drop table object and recreate 
use below reference for the same

[Basics of Foreign Keys in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757181/basics-of-foreign-keys-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

To check what exactly the problem is, use:

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`

There is section "last foreign key error". Look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-monitors.html

My guess is that data type od mail.boxes (id) and mail.users (id) is not the same. (E.g. smallint in one table and integer in second one).

Data in table on which you're trying to create FK could possibly also be problem (are your mailbox ids the same as id of existing users?)

Comment: I deleted all data from tables and checked again for datat types, and they are the same(

Comment: INNODB STATUS writes something like: Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
for correct foreign key definition.

Comment: Do you have any index on mail.users (id) column? E.g. creating  Primary Key on that column should help.

Comment: yep mail.users (id) is already primary key, and still not works(

Comment: Can you provide DDL's ('CREATE TABLE' statements) for both tables?  Maybe, I don't know, mail.boxes.id is AUTOINCREMENT? Is 'id' also primary key in mail.boxes table? Try to create another column (called e.g. user_id) and create FK on it: ALTER TABLE mail.boxes ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES mail.users (id).