# Forward engineering some new relationships fails in filled database(errno 150)

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1005

This is yet another Error 1005, errno 150 on create table thread. I have seen many of them, but none provide an answer to my question.

I have a database in mysql workbench, which is forward engineered and filled with data. Then, I create, from model view, a new table. Afterwards, I add a n:m relationship, between this new table and an existing table in my database.

Finally, I try to synchronize my database. The code generated, for the creation of the two new tables, is this:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`SEntences` (
  `idSEntences` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idSEntences`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Tips_has_SEntences` (
  `Tips_idTips` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `SEntences_idSEntences` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Tips_idTips`, `SEntences_idSEntences`),
  INDEX `fk_Tips_has_SEntences_SEntences1_idx` (`SEntences_idSEntences` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Tips_has_SEntences_Tips1_idx` (`Tips_idTips` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Tips_has_SEntences_Tips1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Tips_idTips`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Tips` (`idTips`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Tips_has_SEntences_SEntences1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SEntences_idSEntences`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`SEntences` (`idSEntences`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_bin;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

I get an error, with this log:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'mydb.Tips_has_SEntences' (errno: 150)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Tips_has_SEntences` (
  `Tips_idTips` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `SEntences_idSEntences` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Tips_idTips`, `SEntences_idSEntences`),
  INDEX `fk_Tips_has_SEntences_SEntences1_idx` (`SEntences_idSEntences` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Tips_has_SEntences_Tips1_idx` (`Tips_idTips` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Tips_has_SEntences_Tips1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Tips_idTips`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Tips` (`idTips`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Tips_has_SEntences_SEntences1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SEntences_idSEntences`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`SEntences` (`idSEntences`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_bin

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Running mysql from terminal, with the SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G command, I get this output, from the most recent foreign key error field:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
141007 14:18:53 Error in foreign key constraint of table mydb/Tips_has_SEntences:

    FOREIGN KEY (`Tips_idTips`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Tips` (`idTips`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Tips_has_SEntences_SEntences1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SEntences_idSEntences`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`SEntences` (`idSEntences`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_bin:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
for correct foreign key definition.
```

After researching my problem, I can't figure out what's wrong. All datatypes are the same, the foreign keys are on primary keys(which have primary indexes on them) etc. I researched various stack overflow answers on this error and reviewed this page, linked in one of them: [MySQL Error Number 1005 Can’t create table ‘.\mydb#sql-328_45.frm’ (errno: 150)](http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/) I searched as thoroughly as I could, but the answer could be in there still. In such a case, I am sorry.

Maybe it has to do something with the fact that the old table(Tips) already has data in it. Synchronizing a 1:n relationship, which adds a foreign key in the old table(Tips) though strangely works. if data were the problem, this wouldn't work, as I found in this post: [How to add foreign key to MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613758/how-to-add-foreign-key-to-mysql-table)

On the other hand, adding a 1:n relationship, which would require adding the foreign key of the old table(Tips) to a new one, generates the same errors and logs(with the exception of referring to a table like this: ‘.\mydb#sql-328_45.frm’).

I should note, that these problems occur for any old table of mine(a table already in the database with data). In addition, I am fairly sure I updated mysql workbench, after I filled the database with data, before I continued filling it and before trying to add these new tables. It is now version 6 and running in kubuntu, linux.

What is the problem here and how can it be treated? Is going to extremes, such as exporting database, dropping and importing it the only way? Even in such a case, what should I do exactly? Keep in mind this is a database with many data entries, about 100000.

If you should want any more information, I would provide them from here on.

Tips table creation code:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mydb.Tips;

CREATE TABLE `Tips` (
  `idTips` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `like_count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` longtext CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `created_at` bigint(19) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `todo_count` bigint(19) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `save_count` bigint(19) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Venues_idVenues` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTips`),
  KEY `fk_Tips_Venues1` (`Venues_idVenues`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Tips_Venues1` FOREIGN KEY (`Venues_idVenues`) REFERENCES `Venues` (`idVenues`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin
```

Comment: Can you do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE mydb.Tips` and post the results with your question?

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering whether that was needed. I figured I wouldn't search how to do it, since I didn't know if it was necessary, but your comment provided with both the incentive and the result of said search.
by the way, I know this is a meta question, but just to make sure, you don't get a notification of my edit, right? I have to reply to your comment like this, for that to happen, correct?

Comment: Nick - you're correct that I don't get a notification of the edit and that you need to comment to ping me. On the subject of your question, I'm afraid I don't have any advice. I was hoping I'd see some sort of smoking gun in the `Tips` table definition, even though it's obvious you know your way around, because sometimes a fresh set of eyes helps. But it looks 100% solid to me. Sorry about that, and good luck.

Comment: UPDATE: i did some changes to the model and database. Migrating another database, adding its tables in the eer diagram and creating a new table. My error somehow became errno 121 on a totally different table. This was easily treatable, by renaming that table's foreign keys. I don't really know how even that error could happen, but now everything is working fine. I guess workbench has its days, huh?...so this question...well, this is akward :p Well, I'll leave it open just in case some1 someday posts what could have happened here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

imho you need to synchronize the definition of the `Tips.idTips` column and the `Tips_has_SEntences.Tips_idTips` column.

In particular the character set and collation of the columns do not correspond.

## Resolution

So in the code, do one of the following:

- define the character set or collation of the `Tips_has_SEntences.Tips_idTips` column
  explicitly.

  ```
  `Tips_idTips` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  ```

  or

  ```
  `Tips_idTips` VARCHAR(45) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  ```
- drop the explicit default collation on the `Tips_has_SEntences` table.

  ```
  COLLATE = latin1_bin -- remove this section
  ```
- drop the explicit character set definition on the `Tips.idTips` column.

  ```
  `idTips` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  ```
- specify the `latin1_bin` collation on the `Tips.idTips` column.

  ```
  `idTips` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  ```

*Beware though*: the last two options can cause data loss if, when using an `ALTER TABLE` query, the "to" and "from" character sets are incompatible.
You should be safe, as the `latin1_bin` and `latin1_swedish_ci` collation use the same character set (`latin1`).

## Explanation

### Experiment

When I disabled the troubling foreign key in the `Tips_has_SEntences` `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
--  CONSTRAINT `fk_Tips_has_SEntences_Tips1`
--    FOREIGN KEY (`Tips_idTips`)
--    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Tips` (`idTips`)
--    ON DELETE NO ACTION
--    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```

Ran the queries and did a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on the `Tips` and `Tips_has_SEntences` tables, I found the definition of the two columns the foreign key was coupling, differed a bit.

```
    ...
    `idTips` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
    ...
    `Tips_idTips` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
    ...
```

On the `Tips.idTips` column the *character set* is explicitly set and on the `Tips_has_SEntences.Tips_idTips` column the table's default *collation* is set.

My guess is the foreign key's columns cannot be easily compared and referential integrity is not supported when the collation or character sets of the two columns involved aren't exactly the same.

### Further investigation

Next I ran `SHOW FULL COLUMN` to show the details of the columns in question.

```
Field           Type            Collation          Null    Key
idTips          varchar(45)     latin1_swedish_ci  NO      PRI
...
Tips_idTips     varchar(45)     latin1_bin         NO      PRI
```

### Why the difference in collation?

When I was reading further into [character sets and collations on columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-column.html), the MySQL docs said:

> - If CHARACTER SET X is specified without COLLATE, character set X and its default collation are used.
> - If COLLATE Y is specified without CHARACTER SET, the character set associated with Y and collation Y are used.

To view the default collations and associated character sets I ran `SHOW COLLATION`:

```
Collation               Charset Id      Default Compiled        Sortlen
...
latin1_german1_ci       latin1  5               Yes             1
latin1_swedish_ci       latin1  8       Yes     Yes             1
latin1_danish_ci        latin1  15              Yes             1
latin1_german2_ci       latin1  31              Yes             2
latin1_bin              latin1  47              Yes             1
latin1_general_ci       latin1  48              Yes             1
latin1_general_cs       latin1  49              Yes             1
latin1_spanish_ci       latin1  94              Yes             1
...
```

Now we can see that MySQL resolves the collation of the `Tips.idTips` column to `latin1_swedish_ci`, because that's the default collation for the explicitly set `latin1` character set.

The collation will be resolved by the character set instead of inherited from the table, because the character set was explicitly set on the column. This is exactly how it was specified in the docs, so this is probably the desired behavior.

### Taking it even further

Now I knew the collation of the `Tips.idTips` column was `latin1_swedish_ci`. So instead of explicitly changing the character set of the `Tips_has_SEntences.Tips_idTips` column, I thought I could also just change the collation to `latin1_swedish_ci`.

```
`Tips_idTips` VARCHAR(45) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
```

This also works.
Interestingly `SHOW CREATE TABLE` now says the column was/should be created with this line:

```
`Tips_idTips` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
```

## Conclusion

Character sets, collation *and* foreign keys together are hell.
I prefer integer columns for foreign keys, instead of string/text types, when I have a choice. And now I know why :)

Looking at the code you posted, this seems to be a problem with all "old" tables in your database as all text columns seem to have the character set `latin1` defined explicitly.

Comment: Perfect! Sorry if it took too long to accept your answer, I hadn't checked my emails in a long time. I also wanted to carefully read it. Since I moved on, it would be impossible to recreate the exact circumstances of this error's creation on my database. Your research though is as close as it can get and makes perfect sense!