# database for every user? or every one in same database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am building a webApp with .net in C# that allow the users to open some projects, and in every project they have data include maps and tables in MYSQL for the items on the maps. (every one have the same tables).
I'm wondering how should i build the sql structure between 2 options:
1) every one who registered to the site will get a new database to him self.
2) every one will get a unique ID and every item in the tables will have more column for this id, and i will select only this items by the ID.

what will be more effective?

Comment: Creating a database for any instance of a particular entity seems unnecessarily troublesome, and certainly uncommon.  Unless there's a *really* good reason to go with Option 1 that you haven't mentioned, Option 2 seems like the clear choice.

Comment: The only concern with Option 2 is database size and performance. But that can usually be overcome with throwing more hardware at it, and clever indexing. However, that's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answerers mentioned already it is quite uncommon to create a database for each user. But adding user_id to the every column straightaway might not be a good idea either.

Ideally, you should properly design the relationship between different data (users, maps, items in your case) and use correct indexing/keys to have a flexible and efficient schema.

An example design can be:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
 int id NOT NULL,
 .... // user data fields will come here...
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE map (
 int id NOT NULL,
 .... // map data fields will come here...
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE item (
 int id NOT NULL,
 .... // item data fields will come here...
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE map_has_item (
  int map_id NOT NULL,
  int item_id NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (map_id, item_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (map_id) REFERENCES map (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES item (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE user_has_map (
  int user_id NOT NULL,
  int map_id NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, map_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (map_id) REFERENCES map (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The design above will help you write simple queries relevant to your application. All the queries using the indexes above will be fast too.

Additionally, it will be flexible enough for potential feature additions. For instance, if it becomes possible for other users to contribute to maps of an another user, you can add a permission/role column to user_has_map table and add new rows by setting this column properly.

The foreign keys defined above can be improved to ensure data integrity (having semantically correct data on the database). You can set ON DELETE and ON UPDATE triggers to simplify cleaning up when a map or user is removed from database. You can learn more about foreign keys by following the links below:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

[Basics of Foreign Keys in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757181/basics-of-foreign-keys-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

One database.  Unique IDs.  Just about every stored procedure or SQL statement will have "WHERE UniqueID = " in it.