# wrong steps in creating foreign key, returned zero row in FK table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I pull off from my project for a while because I stucked. I opened up my localhost to study phpmyadmin which for me the UI is confusing. So I created 2 table, set primary key and foreign key in them, let say table A has PK and table B has FK. I insert data into table A, but the table B still remain zero row of data. Why?

I strange thing in phpmyadmin, u can only set a column to have FK only if it's unique or u set the index to it. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally intended. If a table has a foreigen key this only means, that if you enter a row of data to table b, these means that this has to be present in table a as well. So it is mainly to keep your data in a consistent state. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757181/basics-of-foreign-keys-in-mysql) for basics about foreigen keys and more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Alternativly to phpmyadmin checkout MySQL-Workbench.

Hope this helps you for the start.

Comment: It means that I didn't did anything wrong? I notice if table A PK has let say a 1 int, in the table B's FK have only that value. so PK and FK wasn't about relationship? it's just the matter of data consistency?

Comment: It is indeed about relationship. It says a value that is present in your foreign key column in table b MUST be present in table a. But it does not say, that an entry in table a HAS to be present in table b. So it says something about a realtionship but furthermore about consistency. Checkout the links.

Comment: ok I understand a litte bit now. FK can be said is a reference? once PK been update / del, it will affect the FK? right?

Comment: Yes, you can see the FK as a reference. When the PK is deleted/updated it depends on how you define the "ON DELETE" and "ON UPDATE"-Action. for the FK. You could also define "ON DELETE" => NO ACTION. The result will be, that you cannot delete the PK. Please do not forget to cast your vote or mark an answer as correct.

Comment: TQ so much for the explanation