# Should I make a FK relation on which table?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables like:

```
-- users
+----+--------+---------------------+----------+--------------------+
| id |  name  |       email         | password |      cookie        |
+----+--------+---------------------+----------+--------------------+

-- user_detail
+---------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| user_id | age |       about       |    birthday    |
+---------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I need to make a relation between `users(id)` and `user_detail(user_id)` columns. Now I want to know, should I open `user_detail` table and create a relation on the `user_id` column of it *(which refers to `users(id)`)* or vice versa?

Comment: Downvoter please leave a comment and explain what's wrong with my question?

Comment: And what is a *definition* of FK? And what does a FK constraint say? And when you googled your title you found/learned...? PS Downvote arrrow mouseover text: "This question does not show any research effort; ...". PPS  A relation is a table, You mean relationship.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basics of Foreign Keys in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757181/basics-of-foreign-keys-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for syntax like this:

```
alter table user_details add constraint fk_user_details_user_id
    foreign key (user_id) references users(id);
```

Comment: Ok thx. Just why not `alter table users add constraint fk_user_id foreign key (id) references user_detail(user_id);` ?

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . Because the foreign key is the `user_id` in `user_details`, so that is where the definition goes.  `user.id` is the *primary key* of that table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why do you answer a question like this that is an obvious duplicate & should be downvoted?