# SQL inheritance

Tags: c#, sql

Is it possible to have inheritage in SQL?
I'm trying to make an app in c# that manages the student's grades.
For exemple: the database 'university' contains all faculties, the database faculties contains departments, departments courses, courses the students and so on.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think OP is actually asking about inheritance here, but just a simple foreign-key-based multi-table database.

Comment: That sounds more like a simple relational model than inheritance. What common properties / structures between objects do you have that would suggest inheritance?

Comment: Inheritance enables new objects to take on the properties of existing objects. So, what are the common attributes that you keep in different tables ?
You can use simple relational model which use primary key and foreign key concept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basics of Foreign Keys in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757181/basics-of-foreign-keys-in-mysql)

Comment: @CSI, i think you might need to do some research on simple databases and how to design them. Id suggest looking around for simple tutorials and ones related to C#. I don't think we can help you at this level

Comment: It depends on the type of database. Whether it is a **relational** db or a NoSQL database makes a big difference. If it is a rdbms you can probably use foreign keys for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No inheritance BUT,
Just implement primary key and foreign key concept in your relational modal in a correct manner so you will be able to get the desired result as you want from inheritance.